# Grails Quartz plugin removing triggers on startup with persistence turned on

Tags: java, oracle, grails, quartz-scheduler

I'm encountering the following problem: I've got a grails app, with the quartz plugin, and a persistent storage (Oracle). My job class has an empty triggers block like so:

```
class VodServerJob {
    static triggers = {}
    def volatility = false;
    def durability = true;
    def concurrency = false;
    def group = "MyGroup"
    def execute(context) { }
}
```

...but I programatically add the triggers as I go along (letting the user schedule kick-off times for a job). When I shut down the app, the triggers are still in the database. But on startup, the triggers are removed, defeating the point of persistent storage.

My config is as follows:

```
quartz {
    autoStartup = true
    jdbcStore = true
    waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown = true
}

environments {
    test { quartz { autoStartup = false } }
}
```

and my properties are as follows:

```
#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_

#============================================================================
# Configure Datasources  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.27.5.18:1521:dcrm
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = <hidden, but valid>
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = <hidden, but valid>
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 5
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery=select 0 from dual
```

According to everything I can see, this should allow for DB persistence, and yet, it's getting removed on startup. Anyone have any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer on this one. Triggers are set to `volatile` by default, which means they are deleted on startup. Just set `volatility` of the trigger to `false` as follows for your triggers to be indefinitely persisted.

`trigger.setVolatility(false);`

Otherwise, they'll get wiped.